# javascript addEventListeners

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an arbitrarily long list of divs and each one has a button with the same class name that is meant to make a form appear and prompt the user to add a new task. To achieve this I need the correct List Id to which the task has to be added. Since the form is a div external from the one that contains list in I only have access to a global array of lists and I don't know to which one append the task.

This is the HTML that displays all the lists

```
<?php foreach($Liste as $lista) :?>


    <div class="list-container">
        <h1><?= $lista->getNome() ?></h1>

        <div class="tasks">
            <?php $compiti=$lista->loadCompiti();

            ?>
            <?php foreach($compiti as $compito) :?>
                <div class="task-container">
                    <h3 class="task-title"><?=$compito->getNome() ?></h3>
                    <p> Due date: <?=$compito->getDueDate()?></p>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </div>

        <button class="addTask">Add Task</button>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is the prompt that appears when Add Task is clicked in one of the lists

```
<div class="appear hide " id="taskAdder">
    <button class="hideB" id="hideBTN">X</button>

    <form action="/task/add" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="NomeTask" placeholder="Task name">
        <input type="text" name="dueDate" placeholder="date" >
        <textarea name="desc" placeholder="description" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Create</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and here is the js that is running behind this

```
let form = document.getElementById('form');
let button= document.getElementById('prompt');
let hide = document.getElementById('hideBTN');


let tasksBTN=document.getElementsByClassName('addtask');
let taskAdder=document.getElementById('taskAdder');

for(let i=0; i<tasksBTN.length; i++){
    tasksBTN[i].addEventListener('click', ()=>appear());
}

button.onclick=function () {
    form.classList.remove('hide');

};



hide.onclick=function () {

    form.classList.add('hide');
};

function appear() {
    taskAdder.classList.remove('hide');
}
```

Comment: where are you trying to assign javascript event listeners, where are they defined and what do they do? Please add all relevant javascript. Presumably you are attaching listners to `addTask` class members?

Comment: just added my javascript

Comment: How, using the various functions / classes you have already been using, would you obtain the `correct List Id`? Have you added said List ID anywhere in the HTML structure?

Comment: Each list container is generated from a list, as you can see in the foreach loop, that list object has all the informations about the list that geberates the container

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('addtask');` Note that the parameter is case sensitive in standards mode.

Comment: Let me just clarify here: You've got one single form hidden on your page. For each list item, there is a button that will show the form, and you just have to figure out **which list item** "summoned" the form?

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler can take an argument which gives you access to the button which was clicked. Then you can check its ID or location in the DOM to determine which button it was.

Your loop:

```
for(let i=0; i<tasksBTN.length; i++){
    tasksBTN[i].addEventListener('click', ()=>appear());
}
```

becomes:

```
for(let i=0; i<tasksBTN.length; i++){
    tasksBTN[i].addEventListener('click', appear);
}
```

And the handler:

```
function appear() {
    taskAdder.classList.remove('hide');
}
```

becomes:

```
function appear(e) {
    e.target.classList.remove('hide');
}
```

Comment: This is a good step forward but it is not actually what I need. I need to find a way to access the list Id from the list object in my DOM

Comment: @gloria00 In your question, you say, "This is the prompt that appears when Add Task is clicked in one of the lists" but it isn't clear where that html is embedded into the document because the code for your button clearly doesn't do it. However the list id relates to your button in the DOM, you can access it relative of `e.target` in my last code segment.